# How to load a matrix from a file without knowing its size and without multiple reading?

Tags: c, io

My exercise is to load 2 matrices from 2 files with unknown sizes and multiply them together if it is possible. I should also load each file once. I could do it with loading the file twice as you can see below, but how could I do with loading the file only once?

```
typedef struct matrix_ {
    int r, c;
    double* dat;
} matrix;

int rows(char* fn) {
    int lines = 1;
    int ch;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fn, "r");
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == '\n') {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    return lines;
}

matrix loadmatrix(char* fn) {
    FILE* file = fopen(fn, "r");
    int size = 5*5;
    matrix mat;
    mat.r = rows(fn);
    mat.dat = malloc(size*sizeof(double));
    double input;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &input)==1) {
            if(i == size-1) {
                size = 4*size;
                mat.dat = realloc(mat.dat, size*sizeof(double));
            }
            mat.dat[i] = input;
            i+=1;
        }
    } while (!feof(file));
    mat.c = ((i+1)/(mat.r));
    return mat;
}
```

Comment: [while (!feof(fp)) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you, I will read it later because It will surely be useful later on. But is it helpful in my actual problem?

Comment: May be, it's worth to read it soon. I think it's part of your problem. Btw. you probably will find inspriation in the answers how to solve your issue.

Comment: You could expose sample input. Imagine you have 6 values: Is it 6x1, 3x2, 2x3, or 1x6 matrix? The line ends might provide the necessary hint. In this case, you should read the files in a way that provides this info as well. (May be, read lines, then evaluate what is in line.)

Comment: Or ... read all values into a 1-d matrix that is easier to reallocate, then calculate the indices with `x + y * row_length`

Comment: Try reading the file in line-by-line, which allows you to count rows. With each line, use `sscanf` to extract the values in the columns. Once you have read the first line, you know the number of columns in the matrix. Keep a counter to indicate which position into your `matrix.data` you write values, and to know when to increase the size of your matrix's memory. `realloc` when needed, increasing the size of `matrix.data` by one row (the number of columns) at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file line-by-line, and for each line, read in each value with [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).

Every line is a row and every value in it is in a column. On the first row, count the columns as you go, and count the rows at every newline. If you need more space in your `data` array, [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) one more row's worth of space (`matrix.cols * sizeof(double)`).

Using [`read_line`](https://gist.github.com/Druid-of-Luhn/d1a85f366ceecfc3c2dc5491e3d25cb4) for portably reading in a line, we have:

```
#define MIN_SIZE (5 * 5)

typedef struct matrix {
    size_t  rows;
    size_t  cols;
    double *data;
} matrix;

matrix loadmatrix(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open file '%s' for reading\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    matrix mat = {
        .rows = 0,
        .cols = 0,
        .data = calloc(MIN_SIZE, sizeof(double)),
    };
    // You should check mat.data != NULL here, but I omit it to ease reading
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t data_size = MIN_SIZE;
    while (read_line(file, &line) > 0) {
        double value;
        // Keep reading values into this row
        size_t offset = 0;
        int read_chars = 0;
        while (sscanf(line + offset, "%lf%n", &value, &read_chars) == 1) {
            offset += read_chars;
            if (mat.rows == 0) {
                ++mat.cols;
            }
            // Increase the size of the matrix by one more row if more space is needed
            if (index >= data_size) {
                data_size += mat.cols;
                mat.data = realloc(mat.data, sizeof(double) * data_size);
                if (mat.data == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                        "could not allocate more space for matrix: %zu\n",
                        data_size);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            mat.data[index++] = value;
        }
        ++mat.rows;
        free(line);
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Comment: @Botond I have fixed the `read_line` link to a gist that I wrote. Alternatively, you can use `POSIX`/`glibc`'s `getline` (`man getline`) if you have it available (it takes different parameters from what I used here).

Comment: Thank you! The read_line is working now. But I have a problem what I can't solve: I tested it with 2 3x3 matrices, but it did not read their last element. I tried to look for the problem, but I could not find it. Did I mess something up?

Comment: It works well if I add an extra line at the end of the file, but I could not fix it.

Comment: @Botond What exactly do you mean by that? This solution expects the file to contain the matrix and only the matrix, with no extra lines or invalid data.

Comment: I know. But if I make a file with 3 lines: "1 2 3" & "4 5 6" & "7 8 9", It will only read the first 8 elements i.e. it will miss the 9. But if I make a file with 4 lines: "1 2 3" & "4 5 6" & "7 8 9" & "" i.e. if I add an extra line, it will read all 9 elements.

Comment: @Botond I believe that this could be an issue with my `read_line` function, which expects the last character to be a `\n`, but your file does not end with one (while vim added one to my file). I have updated the `read_line` gist to fix this. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!